# Child element is not populating correctly when it is xpath in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

First I am finding one Parent element using Xpath and again I am trying to the find the child element using Xpath using findelements. But I am getting all the elements in the web driver. When I use find by **tagName** its populating correctly.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://indianfrro.gov.in/frro/FormC/menuuserreg.jsp");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Up (Registration)"));
    //Parent Element
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[@align='left']"));
    List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
    System.out.println("Total Count is: " + elements.size());
```

Result is: Total Count is: 4

```
    List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total Count is: " + elements.size());
```

Result is: Total Count is: 1

Selenium Version: 2.48.2
Browser Version: 44.0.2

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//a"));
```

The `.` before `//a` is very important as it limits the scope of the search to children of `element`.